# Number of Good pairs in O(n)

Tags: java, arrays

// can someone please explain what's happening inside the for loop

```
public int numIdenticalPairs(int[] A) {
    int res = 0, count[] = new int[101];
    for (int a: A) {
        res += count[a]++;
    }
    return res;
}
```

Comment: Hi  Himanshu. Welcome to posting on StackOverflow. For this type of question, you should not be afraid to first offer your own theory as to what is happening in the code. There are  a lot of people posting homework questions on StackOverflow and while the community is happy to assist, it also expects people to first attempt to solve the exercise themselves.  [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Kind Regards.

Comment: It has to do with counting potential pairings between the same elements. The number of pairs works out into a series. If you have one value, it adds 0 to sum. If you have two values, it adds 1 to sum. If you have three values, it adds another 2 for a total of 3 possible pairs. If four, add 3 for 6 total pairs. If five, add 4 for 10 total pairs. Ect. Visibly draw out each identical value as a node and draw lines connecting each identical node to each other identical node. This formula sums up each of those lines for every collection of connected nodes.

Comment: Looks like count[] will contain the frequency of each value (0..100) in A and res will get the sum of all double occurrence counts like Tim explained. Because count[] is increased after the +, the value in res will remain 0 when all values in A are unique. It will get a value >0 when values in A are contained more than once. Say length of A is 100. In that case, max value of res is 99. Then, all values in A are equal (one group). With two groups, you will get res=98. So in effect, res is a measure for the amount of grouping that occurs in A.

Comment: @Goodies Your last bit regarding what the max value of `res` is incorrect. `res` is a summation of all pairings of identical values. Pairings are counted by adding the current number of identical values for each new identical value added since a new identical value can pair with every previous identical value. So if `int[] A` was 100 of the same value, then `res` would be equal to 0+1+2+3+...+96+97+98+99 == 99 * 50 == 4,950 total pairs.

Answer (score 1):

You iterate over an array of interger which work as your indices in the new generated count[]. The result sums up all the values in the "count" array that where visited. So if your input array has only unique numbers the result will always be 0. Also your inputArray must not contain more than 101 unique values otherwise your index is out of bounds.

```
e.g.
input array: [0,1,2] -> result=0
input array: [1,1,2] -> result=1
...
```

the more often a value is in your input-array the bigger inpact this value has on your result.

Answer (score 0):

You use post increment, this mean you return the value of count[a] to res and then increment the value.
So res will have the sim of count values before the increment but the values in count will increase by 1

Answer (score 0):

The counting of pairs between identical values forms a mathematical series. Lets consider each identical value as a node in a node grid containing each other identical value. The math works out that for each additional node added to the grid, it will add the same number of pairs to the grid as the number of nodes already in the grid (since it can pair with every node already in the grid).

```
0 Node in Grid
+1 Node 
Number of Pairs: 0

1 Node in Grid
+1 Node
Number of Pairs: 1 = (0 + 1)

2 Node in Grid
+1 Node
Number of Pairs: 3 = (0 + 1 + 2)

3 Node in Grid
+1 Node
Number of Pairs: 6 = (0 + 1 + 2 + 3)
```

And so on. The formula you have above is keeping track of this increasing node count of each identical value. It's then also adding this node count to the total sum `res` variable. So your loop is adding the current count of identical values, then incrementing that count of identical values for the next time it gets another identical value.